# asp.net mvc httpcontext access options

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Let's have a action filter where I'm accessing the httpcontext in two ways.

```
public class Filter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
     {
            var context1 = context.HttpContext;
            var context2 = HttpContext.Current;     
     }
}
```

My question, if there is any difference between those two instances except the fact that accessing the instance through HttpContext.Current makes the code test unfriendly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not difference as they are pointing at the same object